# Is it appropriate to ask a question regarding processing time for a major electronics component supplier?

Tags: discussion

I placed an order from a major brand-name electronics component supplier for spare parts and accessories from their online store (not a reseller) and it's been almost a month and it is still "processing".

I can call them and certainly ask for the status of my order but what I don't know is how common it is for such a long lead time on spare parts that I thought would have been readily available.

Is Stack Exchange an appropriate forum to ask whether this kind of lead time is normal for a specific parts supplier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is Stack Exchange an appropriate forum to ask whether this kind of lead time is normal for a specific parts supplier?

Hi, Thanks for asking. However, I would say **no**, that question wouldn't be on-topic here.

- It's not a *technical* question.
- It's not close (IMHO) to the subjects the site aims to cover in the [on-topic list](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
- In these current Covid-affected times, any lead time problem may not be normal for them, and hence any answer would risk becoming outdated (and hence have no value for future readers) even more quickly than usual. (This is a variation of why shopping-type questions are off-topic - too localized (in both time and place) and so have little value for other readers.)
- (Other people might think of more reasons.)

Any issues with your *specific* order might apply just to those parts and their manufacturer, so I would first ask the supplier for an update, as you thought.

If you wanted to discuss that supplier (even though the delay in your case might be specific to the manufacturer instead) I immediately think of the [EEVBlog forums](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/) as somewhere that I would consider asking, because I have seen questions about particular companies asked there before.

Sorry that's probably not the response you wanted.

Comment: This is sufficient. Thank you.